# Parse CLI uploaded without Config folder- App Crash major issue

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, linux-mint

I've used the command line tool several times before. I recently installed it on a new desktop (Linux Mint) to upload some new cloudcode. I installed it via CURL.

It kept asking for a password/email each time I typed 'Parse deploy'. It never normally does this so it is suspicious. It also didn't create a 'config' folder (only 'public' and 'cloud' folders).

I re-uploaded a previous version of main.js (which defeintely works) on another PC which I've used before (and has the normal cloud, config & public folders).

However it still doesn't work- I suspect whatever "bug" was uploaded when I installed it on Mint- is still causing the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of the Parse CLI tool is NOT backward compatible unless you specify it. They really should make this more clear.

So, if your app is the Parse SDK version 1.2.14 you would type (in your bash/cmd):

`parse jssdk 1.2.14`

`parse deploy`

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-command-line-gets-a-power-up/

Comment: I should add, your CLI folders are irreverent in your case. The config folder would (I think) hold your login details so you don't have to login each time you do a "parse deploy"